# Не могу понять в чем ошибка (hashlib)

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashlib

Создаю программу для брута хешей

Входные данные : `d8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4` , `wordlist.txt` , `md5`

То что должно вывести : qwerty

Ошибка: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hexdigest'`

Когда убираю `.hexdigest()` из кода возникает ошибка : `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "_hashlib.HASH") to str`

```
from colorama import Fore, init
import hashlib
init()
print ('Starting...')

# USER DATA
userhash = input ("Input HASH : ")
userword = input ("Input PassList : ")
useralg = input ("Input Algorithm : ")

# brute
wordlist = open(userword,"r",encoding='utf-8')
for line in wordlist:
    hashpass = hashlib.new (useralg)
    hashpass.update (line.encode("utf-8"))
    if hashpass == userhash:
        print (Fore.GREEN + line.hexdigest())
    else:
        print (Fore.RED + "PassErr", line.hexdigest())
```

После исправления все равно не работает, вывод программы:

```
PassErr c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
PassErr e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
PassErr d8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4
```

Должно вывести `qwerty`

```
from colorama import Fore, init
import hashlib
init()
print ('Starting...')

# USER DATA
userhash = input ("Input HASH : ")
userword = input ("Input PassList : ")
useralg = input ("Input Algorithm : ")

# brute
wordlist = open(userword,"r",encoding='utf-8')
for line in wordlist:
    hashpass = hashlib.new (useralg)
    hashpass.update (line.rstrip('\n').encode("utf-8"))
    if hashpass == userhash:
        print (Fore.GREEN + hashpass.hexdigest())
    else:
        print (Fore.RED + "PassErr", hashpass.hexdigest())
```

Comment: `hashpass.hexdigest()`, а не `line.hexdigest()`

Comment: На каких входных данных такие ошибки? Укажите в вопросе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как правильно заметил Sergey Gornostayev, вместо `line.hexdigest()` должно быть `hashpass.hexdigest()`:

```
from colorama import Fore, init
import hashlib
init()

line = "some text"
useralg = "md5"

hashpass = hashlib.new(useralg)
hashpass.update(line.encode("utf-8"))
print(Fore.GREEN + hashpass.hexdigest())
# Выведет 552e21cd4cd9918678e3c1a0df491bc3 зеленым цветом
```

Также учитывайте, что строки прочитанные из файла заканчиваются на символ `'\n'`, который нельзя ввести через `input`, поэтому хеши у вас при всем желании не совпадут. Нужно обрезать перенос строки из считанной строки, потом уже считать хеш:

```
wordlist = open(userword,"r",encoding='utf-8')
for line in wordlist:
    hashpass = hashlib.new (useralg)
    # обрезать перенос строки в конце, потом уже кодировать:
    hashpass.update (line.rstrip('\n').encode("utf-8"))  
    if hashpass == userhash:
        print (Fore.GREEN + hashpass.hexdigest())
    else:
        print (Fore.RED + "PassErr", hashpass.hexdigest())
```

По поводу второй ошибки: в Python не все объекты можно складывать между собой с помощью `+`. Ошибка говорит, что вы пытаетесь сложить объект строкового типа (`Fore.GREEN` - это строка `'\x1b[32m'`) с объектом другого типа, что недопустимо. Аналогичная ошибка будет, если попытаться сложить строку с числом:

```
>>> print(Fore.GREEN + 100500)       
                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Чтобы устранить ошибку, можно например привести объект к строке:

```
print(Fore.GREEN + str(100500))
```

Но в данном случае это не то что вам нужно.

#### Обновление

Еще одна проблема: в условии if вы сравниваете объект hashpass (который не является строкой) с введенной пользователем строкой, поэтому условие никогда не выполнится. Чтобы работало правильно, нужно получить из hashpass значение хеша, и его уже сравнивать с введенным хешем.

```
if hashpass.hexdigest() == userhash:
    print (Fore.GREEN + line)  # Выводим саму строку, для которой подошел хеш
else:
    print (Fore.RED + "PassErr", hashpass.hexdigest())
```

Comment: Не совсем понял для чего заменять line.hexdigest() на hashpass.hexdigest() , я создавал программу для брута hash

Comment: line - это считанная из файла строка. У нее нет метода hexdigest. Хеш считается с помощью объекта `hashpass`, в него вы добавляете считанную строку, он автоматически внутри себя считает её хеш. Дальше этот хеш из этого объекта нужно получить с помощью `hashpass.hexdigest()`.

Comment: В качестве словаря использую стантадртый от john , cтроки там не заканчиваются на \n

Comment: @NeonGhost084 не знаю кто такой john. В вопросе вы читаете файл построчно, в конце каждой строки (кроме последней) будет символ переноса строки `'\n'`.

Comment: Исправил программу , но все равно не работает. Так-же взял другой словарь

Comment: Не бывает "не работает", бывает "выдает ошибку", "выдает неправильный результат" и т.д. Что конкретно "не работает"?

Comment: Указал в вопросе

Comment: @NeonGhost084 программа выводит то что вы написали, чтобы она выводила. Если нужно выводить саму строку, считанную из файла, а не ее хеш, просто делайте `print(line)`

Comment: Да, и сравнивать нужно не сам объект hashpass, а полученный из него хеш: `if hashpass.hexdigest() == userhash:`